# Tree drawing with graphviz

Tags: tree, graphviz

Is there a way to force nodes to be rendered on the same y coordinate in graphviz and force others to be rendered one on top of the other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To **constrain nodes to the same rank** (*same y coordinate*), you may use subgraphs and [`rank`](http://www.graphviz.org/content/attrs#drank):

```
digraph g{
    1;
    {rank=same; 2; 3;}
    1 -> 2;
    1 -> 3;
    2 -> 3;
}
```

To **draw nodes on top of each other**, you could use the `group` attribute:

```
digraph g{
    1[group=a];
    {rank=same; 2[group=a];3;}
    1 -> 2;
    1 -> 3;
    2 -> 3;
}
```

From the documentation of [`group`](http://www.graphviz.org/content/attrs#dgroup):

> If the end points of an edge belong to the same group, i.e., have the
>   same group attribute, parameters are set to avoid crossings and keep
>   the edges straight